# ReactJS rerender after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

Learning react and whilst I understand the life cycle of a component, I don't understand that whilst my JSON call is successful it does not render the list of items I've pulled initially. It does render when I add a new item to the list, but that requires me to click the edit button and add a new element.

```
var InterBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            "content" : [],
            "editing" : false,
            "pulled" : false
        }
    },
    componentDidMount: function(){
        var url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
        var tempdata = this.state.content;
        $.getJSON(url, function(data){
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var element = data[i];
                tempdata.push(element.body);
                console.log(tempdata);
            }
        });
        this.setState({"content":tempdata});
        this.forceUpdate();
    },
    addContent: function(e){
        var currentContent = this.state.content;
        currentContent.push(this.refs.content.value);
        this.refs.content.value = "";
        this.setState({"content" : currentContent, "editing" : false});
        this.render();
    },
    changeMode: function(e){
        this.setState({"editing": true});
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        if (this.state.editing)
            return(
                <div>
                    <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
                    <input type="text" ref="content"/>
                    <button onClick={this.addContent}>Add</button>
                </div>
            );
        else{
            var items = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < this.state.content.length; i++) {
                var element = this.state.content[i];
                items.push(<li>{element}</li>);
            }
            return(
                <div>
                    <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
                    <button onClick={this.changeMode}>Edit</button>
                    <ul>
                        {items}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(
    <InterBox title="Hello"></InterBox>,
    document.getElementById('main')
);
```

This is the initial output

[image: The Output]

This what it should look like

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.)** Since **$.getJSON** func is **async**, therefore you should wait response, and after that invoke setState in callback.

```
  let {content} = this.state;
  $.getJSON(url,data=>{
         let result = data.map(e=>e.body);
         this.setState({content:[...content, ...result]}); 
   });
```

**2.)** **You don't need** forceUpdate() and render(), **because setState invoke rendering component for you**.

**3.)** **You shouldn't mutate your state by push()**.It will causing problems and bugs. Instead you may use spread operator or concat, etc

```
//concat returns new array
let {content} = this.state;
this.setState({content:content.concat(result)}); 

//spread operator
let {content} = this.state;
this.setState({content:[...content, ...result]});
```

**4.)** **If you don't want to use arrow func** in callback, **you should use bind(this)**, otherwise you will have **undefined** for setState in callback

```
 let {content} = this.state;
 $.getJSON(url,function(data){
              let result = data.map(e=>e.body);
              this.setState({content:content.concat(result)}); 
         }.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this not only solved my problem but also taught me more about react itself

Answer (score 0):

1. Dont call render function manually i.e. supposed to call by react.
   2.You were setting setState outside your AJAX call response.

   ```
   var InterBox = React.createClass({
       getInitialState: function(){
           return {
               "content" : [],
               "editing" : false,
               "pulled" : false
           }
       },
       componentDidMount: function(){
           var url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
           var tempdata = this.state.content;
           $.getJSON(url, function(data){
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                   var element = data[i];
                   tempdata.push(element.body);
                   console.log(tempdata);
               }
                       this.setState({"content":tempdata});
           });

       },
       addContent: function(e){
           var currentContent = this.state.content;
           currentContent.push(this.refs.content.value);
           this.refs.content.value = "";
           this.setState({"content" : currentContent, "editing" : false});
       },
   changeMode: function(e){
       this.setState({"editing": true});
   },
   render: function(){
       if (this.state.editing)
           return(
               <div>
                   <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
                   <input type="text" ref="content"/>
                   <button onClick={this.addContent}>Add</button>
               </div>
           );
       else{
           var items = [];
           for (var i = 0; i < this.state.content.length; i++) {
               var element = this.state.content[i];
               items.push(<li>{element}</li>);
           }
           return(
               <div>
                   <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
                   <button onClick={this.changeMode}>Edit</button>
                   <ul>
                       {items}
                   </ul>
               </div>
           );
       }
   }
   ```

   });

   ```
   ReactDOM.render(
       <InterBox title="Hello"></InterBox>,
       document.getElementById('main')
   );
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a `this.forceUpdate()` or `this.render()` call. The screen will be refreshed, i.e. `render()` called by React after `this.setState()`.

The reason the data isn't being shown is because you're calling `this.setState()` immediately after calling `$.getJSON()` and not in the success callback of `getJSON()`.

This should work:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var element = data[i];
        tempdata.push(element.body);
        console.log(tempdata);
        this.setState({"content":tempdata});
    }
});
```